# assigning variable to document.getElementById().Innerhtml not working

Tags: javascript

See the code below:

```
var text=["yuppie", "kkkoseh", "watchdog"];

var messageIndex=0;

function looptext (){
    var MessageElement= document.getElementById("happy").innerHTML
    var Message=text[messageIndex];

    MessageElement=Message;
    messageIndex++;

    if(messageIndex>=text.length){
        messageIndex=0;
    }
}

window.onload = function() {
    setInterval(looptext, 1000);
};
```

It doesn't work.

But when I remove `.innerhtml` at variable `MessageElement` and set the `MessageElement.innerHtml= Message` , it works.

Why is it so?
Sorry, I am a newbie learning JavaScript.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because that's how variables and values work in JavaScript. Imagine variables to be like containers. With

```
var MessageElement = document.getElementById("happy").innerHTML
```

the container `MessageElement` will contain a **string**. Later on, with

```
MessageElement = Message;
```

you simply put a new value in the container, overwriting the previous value/content the container had. But it doesn't have any effect on the location where the previous value was coming from.

---

> But when I remove .innerhtml at variable MessageElement and set the MessageElement.innerHtml= Message , it works.

Now the variable contains a reference to the DOM element and

```
MessageElement.innerHtml = Message
```

doesn't *assign* a new value to the variable (doesn't put a new value in the container), it *uses* the value of the variable (container).

Comment: Thank you.. 

I am just curious, Is there a way to include .innerHtml into a variable ? A variable to store the reference point.

Comment: @user3322381: No, JavaScript is assign-by-value, not assign-by-reference.

Answer (score 0):

innerHTML return a string not e pointer to the document.getElementById("happy")'s text node.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var text=["yuppie", "kkkoseh", "watchdog"];

var messageIndex=0;

function looptext (){
document.getElementById("happy").innerHTML = text[messageIndex];
messageIndex++;
if(messageIndex>=text.length){
    messageIndex=0;
}
}    
window.onload = function() {
setInterval(looptext, 1000);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

@Felix King is correct.

To test how it is actually behaving I myself tried the below snippet on W3Schools.
And I found:

1. var MessageElement = document.getElementById("happy") - assigns the element (in my example - http://www.microsoft.com/)
2. alert(m) thus displays - http://www.microsoft.com/
3. m.innerHTML = "Atul"  - assigns Atul to the element.
4. However, value of m was still **http://www.microsoft.com/** as Felix rightly said - 'MessageElement.innerHtml = Message, doesn't assign a new value to the variable'.

   ```
   <html>
   <head>
   <script>
   function changeLink()
   {
   var m = document.getElementById("myAnchor"); //assigns http://www.microsoft.com/
   alert(m); //
   m.innerHTML = "Atul"
   alert(document.getElementById("myAnchor").innerHTML + " new");
   document.getElementById('myAnchor').innerHTML=m;
   }
   </script>
   </head>
   <body>

   <a id="myAnchor" href="http://www.microsoft.com">Microsoft</a>
   <input type="button" onclick="changeLink()" value="Change link">

   </body>
   </html>
   ```

Thanks Felix :)